# I cannot draw the image in chrome correctly

Tags: javascript, image, html, canvas, draw

Here simple code1 which work fine [Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/Z2UzF/show/) ,I want the same result in code2

Here the code2 [Demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/Z2UzF/1/show/) which have two problems.

1. **The scale is not correct to 1400x700 pix**
2. I can only successes to draw from inside `function loadImage()`

   ```
      function loadImage(){
           oG.width = 1400;
           oG.height = 700;
           oG.drawImage(scrollImg,0,0);
       }
   ```

   **I want to draw from** `scrollObject.draw()`

   ```
       var scrollObject = {
           draw : function() {
               oG.drawImage(scrollImg,0,0);
           }
       };
   ```

How can I do that ?
Many thanks.

code1;

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
 body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }

#mycanvas{

    border: 1px solid #9C9898;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body >
   <canvas id="mycanvas" width="1400" height="700" ></canvas>
   <script type="text/javascript">

  // get the canvas element using the DOM http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/Z2UzF/show/
 var context = document.getElementById('mycanvas').getContext("2d");
    context.width = 1400 ;
    context.height = 700 ;

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "http://s9.postimage.org/433ecr79b/grid.png";
    img.onload = function () {
        context.clearRect(0,0,1400,700);
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

code2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title> image not display correct</title>
    <style type='text/css'>
    body {
      background-color:black;
    }
    .Container {
      position: relative;
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto;
      top:10px;
      background-image:url('http://s8.postimage.org/jnu65wk2d/Box_Grass200x100.jpg');
      background-repeat:repeat;
      width:1000px;
      height:500px;
      z-index:0;
      overflow:hidden;
    }

    #layer1{
      position:absolute;
      padding:0;
      margin: 0px;
      z-index:2;
      top:-100px;
      left:-200px;
      width:1400px;
      height:700px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body >
    <div class="Container"> 
        <canvas id="layer1">LAYER1</canvas>
    </div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>//http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/Z2UzF/1/show/

           function loadImage(){
                oG.width = 1400;
                oG.height = 700;
                oG.drawImage(scrollImg,0,0);
            }   

            //layer 1 image then will be object objectGame = oG
        var oG = document.getElementById('layer1').getContext("2d");
                scrollImg = new Image();
                scrollImg.src = "http://s9.postimage.org/433ecr79b/grid.png"; //image size 1400x700px
                scrollImg.onload = loadImage;

            var scrollObject = {
            // Basic attributes

                draw : function() {
                    oG.drawImage(scrollImg,0,0);
                }
            };

            // Now moving it
            function move() {
            //handle with object background
            //clearRect(x, y, width, height)    
                oG.clearRect(0,0,1400,700);
                scrollObject.draw();
            }

        move();

        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just drawImage(img,0,0,1400,700);. It full

Comment: Please enter to this example which I build [Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/Z2UzF/3/show/) you need first to click on the screen after loading the page then you need to press on the key Arrow until the image display tell me if I am wrong Thanks

Comment: This error when scrollVal is > imgWidth or <0. check arg scrollVal

Answer (score 0):

You can only draw on `loadImage()`, because when you trigger `move()` the image have not been loaded yet. You can use a `assetmanager` to download your assets like images, sounds etc. Here is a great guide to build one - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/games/assetmanager/

And for the scale, you can pass a width and height argument to the `drawImage` function.

`context.drawImage(image, x, y, width, height);`

You are also setting the height and width of the `2d-context`, that you cannot do. Set the width and height in the `<canvas>` attributes. I once had problems with height/width when I used `css`, so I would not recommend setting the width/height there.

Comment: Please enter to this example which I build [Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/Z2UzF/3/show/) you need first to click on the screen after loading the page then you need to press on the key     Arrow until the image display **tell me if I am wrong** Thanks

Comment: yes but when I want to change somthing small in the code everting not work like the example which i provide code2 [demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/Z2UzF/2/)

Comment: You have to be more specific in order for me to help you. What is it that is different from code2 than in the code from the comment ^^ ?